# Is it possible to control content on different pages by checkboxing wich content is shown where on a wordpress theme page?

Tags: plugins, widgets, sidebar

i have created a sidebar in my wordpress site.

i want this sidebar to be displayed on each of my pages and subpages in their respective admin editors.

i want the sidebar to contain a list of specific posts with checkboxes to select them independantly or together.

each checked post must then be displayed on my site where i call the sidebar.

is this possible? can anybody direct me towards a plugin that can accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the WordPress [Settings API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API) to do what you're looking for.

You can follow this - [WordPress Settings API Tutorial](http://ottopress.com/2009/wordpress-settings-api-tutorial/) *( www.ottopress.com )* to setup an options page, and depending upon the options saved in database you can show different content.

**Example -**

```
<?php
// get the stored value in variable - foo
$foo = get_option('option_name');

if ( $foo == 1 ) {
    echo 'check box in CHECKED';
} else {
    echo 'check box in NOT CHECKED';
}
```

#### Update -

Yup there's [Options Framework plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/options-framework/) plugin which can be used for this purpose.

> The Options Framework Plugin makes it easy to include an options panel in any WordPress theme. It was built so developers can concentrate on making the actual theme rather than spending time creating an options panel from scratch. It's free to use in both commercial and personal projects, just like WordPress itself.

<sup>- A Quote from plugin's description</sup>

Comment: sorry i am searching for something more simple and fast to implement. preferably a plugin :/

Comment: Ok, there's only way I could think of is - using Settings api. You can use the `Options Framework plugin` to achieve that. _( See my Udpdate )_

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question.

You can control what is shown in your sidebar in the widgets part of your admin module.

http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Widgets

-- if not please rephrase your question.

Comment: i need a plugin that can control the content of my own "sidebars" on my own pages. not in the admin pages

Comment: what do you mean by 'own' sidebars and own pages? Still not clear, but maybe it's just me, I'll see if someone else answers here

Comment: your 'own' sidebars sounds like static html, use the widget API and define additional sidebars instead

Comment: i tried to rephrase my question. hope this is more understandable. thank you for the patience

Answer (score 0):

I found the following plugin that are cabable of doing the job somwhat.

Its called Page Per Sidebar:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/per-page-sidebars/